# Get coordinate of google map_click event Ionic

Tags: google-maps, ionic2, ionic-native

Im trying to read the coordinates of a google map_click event. 
I've tried:

```
map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_CLICK).subscribe((e) => {
 console.log(e.LatLng.lat()); 
})
```

which doesnt work.

I imported googlemap via ionic-native.

Comment: What about trying `console.log(e)` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

so i found out its just `e.lat`